# WebDAV file upload slow

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8, webdav

I am using a WebDAV folder on an Ubuntu root server over SSL.
I connect to the folder through windows' network drive mapping. So far so good.

When I transfer files to the mapped network drive speed is incredibly slow. I already disabled the automatic LAN settings through Internet Explorer (a tip that I found on a couple of [forums](http://oddballupdate.com/2009/12/fix-slow-webdav-performance-in-windows-7/)) but the performance still lacks.

The problem only exists while uploading though. I have tested the server's network connection (up and downstream > 40Mbit) and tried on different PCs (Win7 and Win8).

Interestingly enough, the detailed information in Win8 shows a really fast transfer rate (~50MB/s) from 0 - 99 % but then the file transfer gets stuck - sometimes for seconds, minutes or doesn't finish at all. It seems the bigger the transferred file the worse it gets.

Is this a problem with Windows or with my WebDAV settings? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is a strictly local notwork problem then you may need to investigate problems with the router you are usin. If this is a connection over the internet your problem could be in routers at either end, or with the internet service(s) in use.

Comment: @zeel it's over the internet

Comment: In that case run a speed check (speedtest.net) on both ends. In most cases your upload speed will be significantly lower than your download speed - the result is that transferring files to a server can be incredibly slow even though downloads are very fast.